# Setting text of a label from another class

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `UILabel *employeeNumLabel` in my Firstviewcontroller class. 
Now i want to change the text of that label from a method of my secondviewcontroller class.
I have put the following code in my Secondviewcontroller class :

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
 number ++;

 NSString * numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number];

 [employeeNumLabel setText:numberString]; 
}
```

But there is showing an error : `use of undeclared identifier employeeNumLabel`.
Although i've import the Firstviewcontroller.h in my Secondviewcontroller.m class.

Comment: crate object of Firstviewcontroller in secondViewController and also create @property of employeeNumLabel in Firstviewcontroller. after that access like this - [firstViewControllerObject.employeeNumLabel setText:numberString];

Answer (score 1):

Declare UILabel *employeeNumLabel below @implementaion in Firstviewcontroller.

```
@implementation Firstviewcontroller
 UILabel *employeeNumLabel;
```

Then extern it in secondviewcontroller like

```
 @implementation secondviewcontroller
 extern UILabel *employeeNumLabel;
```

after that use your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your header define  the label

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILable * employeeNumLabel;
```

In the .m file synthesize it

```
@synthesize employeeNumLabel
```

In your init function allocate memory to the label and add it to your view.
Alternatively you can create a IBOutlet and link it to this label.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the Label text you need to do the following thing..

1) You have to make the property of your Label In first view Controller...

2) You need the shared reference of first view controller in second view controller like you can access the label and set the text for same object.

or .. Do one more thing..

1) Take a NSString *lblString ; in you appdelegate class and make its property ..

2) you know you can get the shared reference of appdelegate in your whole application by using following code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; //this will give your appdelegate Object..
```

3) Then in your secondViewController class method...

```
Your_Appdelegate *appdelegate = (Appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appdelgate.lblString = @"YOUR_LABEL_TEXT";
```

4)and then in your FirstViewController.. set The lableText in the same way...

```
 Your_Appdelegate *appdelegate = (Appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
yourLabel.text = appdelgate.lblString;
```

initially what text you want at your label set it in your appdelegate..

May this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

In Firstviewcontroller.h declare employeeNumLabel as extern,

```
  @interface Firstviewcontroller : UIViewController{}
      extern  UILabel *employeeNumLabel;
```

then add  following in Firstviewcontroller.m (@place where global varriable are declared),

```
UILabel *employeeNumLabel;
```

Then import Firstviewcontroller.h in secondviewcontroller.h after that use your code..